# Excel VBA countif debug

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

I am currently writing a code that basically has to go to a database file, check in column B if there's anything in it, if yes, it has to check on column C what are the first 3 numbers and then count it depending on those numbers, then go on the original file and print them, but the code is giving an error 13 'Type mismatch' and i can't figure out why

Also, ideally I could update the file every week and add it in the count if function. I thought about a dictionary but I am not sure how to create it.

```
Sub KPI_Year()

    Dim bodyb As Long
    Dim windshield As Long
    Dim frt_sus As Long
    Dim wheels As Long
    Dim pneumatic As Long
    Dim engine As Long
    Dim transmission As Long
    Dim fuel As Long
    Dim furnishing As Long
    Dim destination_sign As Long
    Dim hvac As Long
    Dim painting As Long
    Dim electrical As Long
    Dim audio As Long
    Dim external_acc As Long
    Dim driver As Long
    Dim spare As Long

    Dim SourceWb As Workbook
    Dim DCP_RC_Wb As Workbook
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Path2 As String
    Path = "........"
    Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path, ReadOnly:=True)
    SourceWb.Activate

    Path2 = ".............."'Set DCP_RC_Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path2, ReadOnly:=True)
    ''DCP_RC_Wb.Activate


    Dim x As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Workbooks(SourceWb).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)


    Dim DCP_presence As Range
    Dim counter As Range

    For x = 2 To lastrow
        DCP_presence = Workbooks(SourceWb).Range("C" & x).Value
        counter = Workbooks(SourceWb).Range("D" & x).Value


        If DCP_presence <> "" Then

            bodyb = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("101*" Or "401*" Or "501*" Or "601*" Or "A01*" Or "B01*" Or "C01*" Or "D01*" Or "E01*" Or "F01*" Or "G01*" Or "H01*" Or "V01*" Or "W01*" Or "102*" Or "402*" Or "502*" Or "602*" Or "A02*" Or "B02*" Or "C02*" Or "D02*" Or "E02*" Or "F02*" Or "G02*" Or "H02*" Or "V02*" Or "W02*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B2) = bodyb

            windshield = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("103*" Or "403*" Or "503*" Or "603*" Or "A03*" Or "B03*" Or "C03*" Or "D03*" Or "E03*" Or "F03*" Or "G03*" Or "H03*" Or "V03*" Or "W03*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B3) = windshield

            frt_sus = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("104*" Or "404*" Or "504*" Or "604*" Or "A04*" Or "B04*" Or "C04*" Or "D04*" Or "E04*" Or "F04*" Or "G04*" Or "H04*" Or "V04*" Or "W04*" Or "105*" Or "405*" Or "505*" Or "605*" Or "A05*" Or "B05*" Or "C05*" Or "D05*" Or "E05*" Or "F05*" Or "G05*" Or "H05*" Or "V05*" Or "W05*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B4) = frt_sus

            wheels = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("106*" Or "406*" Or "506*" Or "606*" Or "A06*" Or "B06*" Or "C06*" Or "D06*" Or "E06*" Or "F06*" Or "G06*" Or "H06*" Or "V06*" Or "W06*" Or "107*" Or "407*" Or "507*" Or "607*" Or "A07*" Or "B07*" Or "C07*" Or "D07*" Or "E07*" Or "F07*" Or "G07*" Or "H07*" Or "V07*" Or "W07*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B5) = wheels

            pneumatic = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("108*" Or "408*" Or "508*" Or "608*" Or "A08*" Or "B08*" Or "C08*" Or "D08*" Or "E08*" Or "F08*" Or "G08*" Or "H08*" Or "V08*" Or "W08*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B6) = pneumatic

            engine = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("109*" Or "409*" Or "509*" Or "609*" Or "A09*" Or "B09*" Or "C09*" Or "D09*" Or "E09*" Or "F09*" Or "G09*" Or "H09*" Or "V09*" Or "W09*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B7) = engine

            transmission = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("110*" Or "410*" Or "510*" Or "610*" Or "A10*" Or "B10*" Or "C10*" Or "D10*" Or "E10*" Or "F10*" Or "G10*" Or "H10*" Or "V10*" Or "W10*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B8) = transmission

            fuel = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("111*" Or "411*" Or "511*" Or "611*" Or "A11*" Or "B11*" Or "C11*" Or "D11*" Or "E11*" Or "F11*" Or "G11*" Or "H11*" Or "V11*" Or "W11*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B9) = fuel

            furnishing = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("112*" Or "412*" Or "512*" Or "612*" Or "A12*" Or "B12*" Or "C12*" Or "D12*" Or "E12*" Or "F12*" Or "G12*" Or "H12*" Or "V12*" Or "W12*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B10) = furnishing

            destination_sign = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("113*" Or "413*" Or "513*" Or "613*" Or "A13*" Or "B13*" Or "C13*" Or "D13*" Or "E13*" Or "F13*" Or "G13*" Or "H13*" Or "V13*" Or "W13*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B11) = destination_sign

            hvac = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("114*" Or "414*" Or "514*" Or "614*" Or "A14*" Or "B14*" Or "C14*" Or "D14*" Or "E14*" Or "F14*" Or "G14*" Or "H14*" Or "V14*" Or "W14*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B12) = hvac

            painting = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("115*" Or "415*" Or "515*" Or "615*" Or "A15*" Or "B15*" Or "C15*" Or "D15*" Or "E15*" Or "F15*" Or "G15*" Or "H15*" Or "V15*" Or "W15*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B13) = painting

            electrical = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("116*" Or "416*" Or "516*" Or "616*" Or "A16*" Or "B16*" Or "C16*" Or "D16*" Or "E16*" Or "F16*" Or "G16*" Or "H16*" Or "V16*" Or "W16*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B14) = electrical

            audio = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("117*" Or "417*" Or "517*" Or "617*" Or "A17*" Or "B17*" Or "C17*" Or "D17*" Or "E17*" Or "F17*" Or "G17*" Or "H17*" Or "V17*" Or "W17*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B15) = audio

            external_acc = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("118*" Or "418*" Or "518*" Or "618*" Or "A18*" Or "B18*" Or "C18*" Or "D18*" Or "E18*" Or "F18*" Or "G18*" Or "H18*" Or "V18*" Or "W18*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B16) = external_acc

            driver = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("119*" Or "419*" Or "519*" Or "619*" Or "A19*" Or "B19*" Or "C19*" Or "D19*" Or "E19*" Or "F19*" Or "G19*" Or "H19*" Or "V19*" Or "W19*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B17) = driver

            spare = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(counter, ("120*" Or "420*" Or "520*" Or "620*" Or "A20*" Or "B20*" Or "C20*" Or "D20*" Or "E20*" Or "F20*" Or "G20*" Or "H20*" Or "V20*" Or "W20*"))
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B18) = spare

        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: hi. there are any error ? or whats  not functioning rigth ?

Comment: Run time error 13 type mismatch but it is not highlighting anything

Comment: There are many syntax errors and you will get a "type mismatch" on every countifs line.  You can do a google search on how to find multiple criteria in a countifs.  You may want to look at your logic.  If you fix the aforementioned, each of your final cell values will either be a zero or one because you are looping through 2 to lastrow and only evaluating a range of 1 cell each time.  The result will be the countif of D & lastrow.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a few changes to your code and see if the error still shows up, however it's hard to give a solution if you don't specify the type of error or in which line it takes place.

In your line:

```
counter = Workbooks(SourceWb).Range("D" & x).Value
```

I would remove the ".Value" bit, since you are using a variable of Range type, this might be causing a problem.

Then in each bit where you copy the information, I have never seen they way you are calling the cell where you want to copy the information, I would change this:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cell(B2) = bodyb
```

To this:

```
NamedWorksheet.Range("B2").Value = bodyb
```

There might be some other problems though, please let me know in which line and what kind of error you are getting and I will be able to help you better.

Comment: Also, it is not highlighting the error which is why i am not able to fix it

Comment: OP has a fundamental misunderstanding of datatype usage, so it might help to address when to use `Range`, `Long`, `String` and likewise a `Range` versus a `.Value`

Comment: @MariaFakhry When the error shows up, if you press Debugg you should be able to locate the line in which the error is taking place. You should also be naming your worksheets, and I'm not sure WorksheetFunction works without "Excel." preceding it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your not selecting the sheet.

try to change

```
lastrow = Workbooks(SourceWb).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
```

To

```
lastrow = SourceWb.Sheets("NAME_OF_THE_SHEET").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
```

Comment: These should end in `.Row` as well